# Excel VBA programming to copy specific rows from sheet1 to sheet2 specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write one vba code which will search data from a specific column of sheet1 and copy those rows and paste those to sheet2. I have written the code but found one problem there. here is the code below.

```
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("D1").Select
    Dim mycode As Worksheet
    Set mycode = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, 4).Value = "high" Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 8)).Copy Destination:=mycode.Range("A" & mycode.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            ElseIf Cells(i, 4).Value <> "high" Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            Range("A2").Value = "No Crtical Logs Found"
            End If
        Next i
    End Sub
```

From sheet1 column D(number4) I am searching data matching "high" and copy paste those rows to sheet2. And if any of the "high" is not there in column D then "No action required" will be written in cell A2 on sheet2. But the problem is when "high" value is not there it is working fine but when "high" value is there in D column sheet1 then all time "no action required" value is coming on cell A2 on sheet2. Please help me to rectify this.

```
No Crtical Logs Found   4/11/2016   Critical    high        192.168.1.1 This is the sample excel sheet  Action Required
```

Regards,
Pinaki

Answer (score 0):

You are moving off *Sheet1* too soon:

```
Sub fhskdfh()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("D1").Select
    Dim mycode As Worksheet
    Set mycode = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        MsgBox i & vbCrLf & Cells(i, 4).Value
        If Cells(i, 4).Value = "high" Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 8)).Copy Destination:=mycode.Range("A" & mycode.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Gary, I don not need the msgbox to show the "high" "low" values rather I want to copy the "High" values and paste on sheet2 and about "low" values "no action" msg will show on sheet2 cell A2. but when the "high" values rows are pasting on sheet2 the "no action" msg is also coming up on cell A2 sheet2.

Answer (score 0):

Change your destination of the "No Crtical Logs Found" message 

From

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Select Range("A2").Value
```

To

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value
```

You do not need to select the cell before assigning a value to it.

Comment: Hi Glenn, Thanks for your comment. I have a column (lets assume cloumn D) which consists the value as "Low" and "High" and my code should be like when the "high" values are found (note: there must be "Low" values also in column D but "high" values may come) from Sheet1, the entire column(s) will copy and paste those to sheet2. But when the column consists only "Low" values that time "No Action" msg is showing on cell A2 on Sheet2 and when column D consists "high" values along with "low" values then it is copying those "high" values and pasting on sheet2 but cell A2 is also showing "No action".